# Error importing cv2 library on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

In one of my scripts (although this also happens when I just import cv2 in a Python 3 file), I'm getting an Import Error when importing cv2 on my Raspberry Pi 4B running Bullseye. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mgerber23/Desktop/Scripts/Security/security.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_store_8
```

I've gone through a bunch of different posts about this trying various pip and sudo apt install commands but nothing seems to work. I've tried:

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
sudo pip install opencv-python
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcairo2-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libhdf5-103 python3-pyqt5 python3-dev -y
```

I've also attempted to reinstall numpy, but that didn't help. I'm currently running numpy version 1.19.5 according to pip(3) show numpy. At one point, there was a long detailed error message specifying that numpy was not in PATH. I'm wondering if this is potentially messing up cv2.

This post seemed to be related (https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/issues/1448), but I don't know enough to understand it, so if someone could slightly dumb it down for me that would be much appreciated.

When trying the following commands:

```
wget https://github.com/prepkg/opencv-raspberrypi/releases/latest/download/opencv_64.deb
sudo apt install -y ./opencv_64.deb
```

I receive the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'opencv:arm64' instead of './opencv_64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opencv:arm64 : Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:arm64 (>= 1.22.0) but it is not installable
                Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:arm64 (>= 1.22.0) but it is not installable
                Depends: libavcodec59:arm64 (>= 5.1.3) but it is not installable
                Depends: libavformat59:arm64 (>= 5.1.3) but it is not installable
                Depends: libavutil57:arm64 (>= 5.1.3) but it is not installable
                Depends: libswscale6:arm64 (>= 5.1.3) but it is not installable
                Depends: python3-numpy:arm64 (>= 1.24.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Maybe the error has something to do with this?

My best guess is that it has something to do with how I installed cv2, but I have no idea what that exact problem could be. Also, I apologize in advance if this question isn't detailed enough, please let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Comment: Do you have `libatomic` installed? What comes back when you run `sudo find / -type f -name '*atom*.so*'` in your shell?

Comment: In any event, it would be helpful if you would expand on what *specifically* you tried in regards to the "*various pip and sudo apt install commands*" you've run to avoid suggesting duplicative courses of action. See also: [ask]

Comment: @esqew Thanks for the feedback. I'll update the question with more information. When I run that command I get 'find: '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied, then /usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0, then finally /usr/libb/arm-linux-gnueabbihf/libsratom-0.so.0.6.8

Comment: https://lindevs.com/install-precompiled-opencv-on-raspberry-pi/ or  https://qengineering.eu/bookworm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is to load Python with `LD_PRELOAD` pointed to the correct location for `libatomic` on your filesystem before running your script or Python REPL. Executing this command in your shell will tell you whether this is a suitable solution or not:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux/gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 python3 -c 'import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)';
```

More info regarding `LD_PRELOAD` is available [elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick).

A more permanent fix is to recompile `opencv` for your system (based on [the original guidance on the `opencv` wiki](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)) with an extra flag for `cmake` using this script below as described in [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15278#issuecomment-1722550352):

```
# Install minimal prerequisites (Ubuntu 18.04 as reference)
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y cmake g++ wget unzip
# Download and unpack sources
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.x.zip
unzip opencv.zip
# Create build directory
mkdir -p build && cd build
# Configure
cmake  ../opencv-4.x
# Build
cmake --build .

# Install minimal prerequisites (Ubuntu 18.04 as reference)
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y cmake g++ wget unzip
# Download and unpack sources
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.x.zip
wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.x.zip
unzip opencv.zip
unzip opencv_contrib.zip
# Create build directory and switch into it
mkdir -p build && cd build
# Configure
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-4.x/modules ../opencv-4.x -DOPENCV_FORCE_LIBATOMIC_COMPILER_CHECK=1
# Build
cmake --build .
```

[A fix for the ultimate root cause seems to be in the pipeline for release in `opencv 5.x`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/24561), but it's not clear when the maintainers expect to release this to the public given [the ongoing crowdfunding effort](https://opencv.org/blog/where-is-opencv-5/) doesn't seem to be close to their target. You could try to build from [the `v5.x` source on GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/5.x), but that'd be treading in uncharted waters and wouldn't necessarily work with the current Python bindings (among other incompatibilities I'm likely overlooking).

Comment: Using LD_PRELOAD doesn't fix the situation. I ran through the rest of the steps exactly as stated, but I am still getting the same error. Any other ideas? I wonder if it's a problem with the permissions for libatomic. I was getting a permissions error somewhere; I'll try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple alternative (as @toyota Supra points out in the comments) is to install a Raspberry Pi-specific build from a prebuilt `.deb` available on GitHub:

```
wget https://github.com/prepkg/opencv-raspberrypi/releases/latest/download/opencv_64.deb
sudo apt install -y ./opencv_64.deb
```

The viability of this method depends in part on how much you trust the build maintainers themselves.

Comment: When I run the second command, I'm getting an error along the lines of: The following packages have unmet dependencies: libgstreamer1.0-0:arm64 (>= 1.22.0) but it is not installable, etc.